# Magento 2 - Custom user edit tab not displaying

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I try to add a new tab on Admin user edit

[image: Admin edit page magento 2]

I use this code,

**adminhtml_user_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="Test_adminhtml_user">
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">custom_tabs</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">Testing\test\Block\Adminhtml\User\Tab\Test</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Test.php**

```
<?php

namespace Testing\test\Block\Adminhtml\User\Tab;

/**
 * Order custom tab
 *
 */
class Test extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'tab/view/test.phtml';

    /**
     * View constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('permissions_user');
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrderId()
    {
        return $this->getOrder()->getEntityId();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order increment id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOrderIncrementId()
    {
        return $this->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('My Custom Tab');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('My Custom Tab');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

**test.phtml**

```
<div class="fieldset-wrapper order-information">
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper-title">
        <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Information for new Order tab') ?></span>
    </div>
    <table class="admin__table-secondary">
        <tbody>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Order ID:') ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $block->getOrderIncrementId(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Last History:') ?></th>
            <td><?php echo __('History of order') ?></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

but it's not displaying on admin user edit page, is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify layout by following code:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_user_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.user.edit.tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">custom_tabs</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Adminhtml\User\Tab\Test</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear cache.

***Note:*** *Make sure your module name start with an uppercase character*

**[Update]**

Add the following method in your block class which will sorting your tab
**[Testing/test/Block/Adminhtml/User/Tab/Test.php]**

```
public function getAfter()
{
    return 'roles_section';
}
```

Comment: It's work perfectly sir, is there any method to add it after "User Role" ?

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Perfect sir, thanks a lot